# How long does the revenge option last?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Hopefully a straight-forward question. I've been receiving a lot of attacks the last few days I'm not too interested in counterattacking right now. How long will I be able to retain the option to get revenge on attackers? I poked around the interwebs, but didn't find anything definitive, with a [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/ClashOfClans/comments/2c7x7g/misc_why_are_some_revenge_replay_options/) thread implying that there might be some time-based restrictions. Are there restrictions on taking revenge beyond having previously attacked the player?

Comment: I don't have any evidence to back this up, but I think as long as the attack still exists in your history of defenses, you can revenge the person.  Of course there are the restrictions of: the attack was not a revenge attack and you have not previously revenged the target.

Comment: My single data point - I have 2 weeks of defense log, all of those I can revenge if I didn't attack first and haven't revenged already.  It's 38 entries total.  I don't think I can draw any definitive conclusions based on this single data point, however.

Comment: I think it's based on your log. There's a limit I think on the number of defenses you can have and that's it. I once had a 2 month old defense (back from when I wasn't getting attacked much, that's quite some time ago though) that I still could revenge. What I would say is: if there's someone you want to revenge that is at the end of your log, chances are that you will lose this log if you get attacked once more.

Answer (score 1):

You can revenge anyone in your defence log *unless* you have already revenged them or they revenged you. Then the option will not be shown. Also, you have to try to revenge when the player is offline or unshielded or else you will not be able to attack them.

Items will not remain in your defence log based on time, there seems to be a limit of 27 items which are cycled out as you get attacked again.

Comment: So, how long will an attack remain in the defense log?

Comment: Forever, there is a limit of items in the defence log however (seems to be 27 when I counted). No time limit to my knowledge.

Comment: Community bumped this question, which caused me to look at my log. I'm much more progressed, so I have a lot more attacks in my defense log now. I counted the number of attacks I can see in the log, and it looks like I have 40.

Comment: I think the number might have a limit (say 40) and upon maintenance breaks or updates, some of them might be removed from the bottom, the same way you can no longer watch replays after updates.

Comment: The maintenance or updates delete the last ones. Letting you with 10 or something like that